# how to gulp rsync locally

Tags: gulp, local, rsync

I'm working on site files outside of my local htdocs that I want to deploy to the local site. I will use gulp-watch to watch for changes, but I'm stumbling on just the rsync set up. File structure:

```
sitename/ -- 
    --htdocs/sites/all/themes/themename
    --source/themes/themename
```

And here's the gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rsync = require('gulp-rsync');

gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  gulp.src('source/**')
    .pipe(rsync({
    root: 'source',
    destination: '/htdocs/sites/all'
  }));
});
```

And when I run `gulp deploy`

```
[11:36:53] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/sitename/gulpfile.js
[11:36:53] Starting 'deploy'...
[11:36:53] Finished 'deploy' after 5.23 ms
```

Nothing is written anywhere. Am I missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` is short for "remote sync", and thus needs a destination somehwere else than your local system. If you want to synchronize stuff from one directory to the other, just use the built-in gulp methods.

```
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
   gulp.src('source/**')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('/htdocs/sites/all');
});
```

This will copy everything you need to the other folder. If you are looking to also delete files, add this to your watcher:

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('./source/**/*', ['deploy']);
watcher.on('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
        // path.relative gives us a string where we can easily switch
        // directories
        del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('./source','/htdocs/sites/all'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, sometimes the easiest stuff evades a beginner. Syntax correction: